# How to stylize a progress indicator which appears after a function called?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to apply a theme for the function? The idea is to stylize circular progress indicator color which appears when licenses are loading.

```
OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () {
        showLicensePage( // how to apply theme to this function?
          context: context,
          applicationIcon: const MyAppIcon(48),
        );
    },
    child: Text(
        AppLocalizations.key(context, 'licenses'),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `showLicensePage` function is really just a simple `Navigator.push`.

```dart
void showLicensePage({
  required BuildContext context,
  String? applicationName,
  String? applicationVersion,
  Widget? applicationIcon,
  String? applicationLegalese,
  bool useRootNavigator = false,
}) {
  assert(context != null);
  assert(useRootNavigator != null);
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: useRootNavigator).push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => LicensePage(
      applicationName: applicationName,
      applicationVersion: applicationVersion,
      applicationIcon: applicationIcon,
      applicationLegalese: applicationLegalese,
    ),
  ));
}
```

You can create your own `showLicensePageWithTheme` where you wrap the `LicensePage` with a `Theme` widget:

```dart
void showLicensePageWithTheme({
  required BuildContext context,
  required ThemeData theme,
  String? applicationName,
  String? applicationVersion,
  Widget? applicationIcon,
  String? applicationLegalese,
  bool useRootNavigator = false,
}) {
  assert(context != null);
  assert(useRootNavigator != null);
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: useRootNavigator)
      .push(MaterialPageRoute<void>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => Theme(
      data: theme,
      child: LicensePage(
        applicationName: applicationName,
        applicationVersion: applicationVersion,
        applicationIcon: applicationIcon,
        applicationLegalese: applicationLegalese,
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```